# Why Broadcastreceiver is not working in the background?

Tags: android

My Broadcastreceiver is not working in the background.I have tried it on Kitkat, lolipop and marshmalw but same case happened.My code is given below.

```
Manifest.xml
`        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
         />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


        <service android:name=".MyAlarmService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiverr" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>`

public class AlarmReceiverr extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // assumes WordService is a registered service
        Intent intentt = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
        context.startService(intentt);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Why are you extending `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, have you tried using `BroadcastReceiver` instead? The receiver's `onReceive` method should be called when the device completed the booting process. Also, add a log when the method is executed to help you `Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive");`

Comment: how the onReceive method can be called when the device completed booting process

Answer (score 0):

If this is running on an Android version >3.0, you need to include an Activity that can be launched first to bring the app out of the stopped state. Otherwise, your Receiver is not going to work.

But try using Priority for broadcast reciever as given below

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiverr" >
            <intent-filter  >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" android:priority="999"
             /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```